# Apache2, MySql not able to start in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, services, phpmyadmin

Trying to start Apache from terminal using following command:

```
systemctl start apache2.service
```

when executing that command getting below error:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Output of `systemctl status apache2.service`:

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-08-28 10:59:14 EEST; 4min 37s ago
  Process: 1051 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

авг 28 10:59:14 GhostInTheShell apachectl[1051]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
авг 28 10:59:14 GhostInTheShell apachectl[1051]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/' for main error log
авг 28 10:59:14 GhostInTheShell apachectl[1051]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/' for error log of vhost defined at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/laravel.conf:1
авг 28 10:59:14 GhostInTheShell apachectl[1051]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/log/apache2/' for error log of vhost defined at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1
авг 28 10:59:14 GhostInTheShell apachectl[1051]: AH00014: Configuration check failed
авг 28 10:59:14 GhostInTheShell apachectl[1051]: Action 'start' failed.
авг 28 10:59:14 GhostInTheShell apachectl[1051]: The Apache error log may have more information.
авг 28 10:59:14 GhostInTheShell systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
авг 28 10:59:14 GhostInTheShell systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
авг 28 10:59:14 GhostInTheShell systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Output of `journalctl | tail`:

```
авг 28 11:19:14 GhostInTheShell org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.desktop[1773]: # Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4423:25: '' is not a valid color name
авг 28 11:19:14 GhostInTheShell org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.desktop[1773]: # Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4433:25: '' is not a valid color name
авг 28 11:19:14 GhostInTheShell org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.desktop[1773]: # Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4445:14: unknown value for property
авг 28 11:20:19 GhostInTheShell kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:54:e6:fc:a6:a5:4b:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
авг 28 11:22:25 GhostInTheShell kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:54:e6:fc:a6:a5:4b:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
авг 28 11:23:32 GhostInTheShell kernel: perf: interrupt took too long (5102 > 5055), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 39000
авг 28 11:23:38 GhostInTheShell gnome-keyring-daemon[1450]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/1, but it's already registered
авг 28 11:24:30 GhostInTheShell kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:54:e6:fc:a6:a5:4b:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
авг 28 11:26:36 GhostInTheShell kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:54:e6:fc:a6:a5:4b:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
авг 28 11:27:00 GhostInTheShell wpa_supplicant[903]: wlp2s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 54:e6:fc:a6:a5:4c [GTK=CCMP]
```

I have same error in MySQL

Output of `systemctl start mysql.service`:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Output of `systemctl status mysql.service`:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-08-28 11:37:47 EEST; 6s ago
  Process: 6209 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 6200 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

авг 28 11:37:47 GhostInTheShell systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
авг 28 11:37:47 GhostInTheShell systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
авг 28 11:37:47 GhostInTheShell systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
авг 28 11:37:47 GhostInTheShell systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
авг 28 11:37:47 GhostInTheShell systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
авг 28 11:37:47 GhostInTheShell systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Comment: the output said `авг 28 10:59:14 GhostInTheShell apachectl[1051]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message` are you sure about that "ServerName" ?

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri I fix this error: AH00558 , but still have this message when i try to start or restart apache2

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri That should not cause the server to fail. It happens all the time in new installations.

Comment: I find it strange that the error log can not be reached. Do you have a directory `/var/log/apache2`?

Comment: @Jos I don't have directory apache2 in /var/log .. What can i do in this case.

Comment: Reinstall Apache2. The log directory should have been created at install time. If that hasn't happened, who knows what else has gone wrong.

Comment: @Jos I fix it without Reinstall , But still have same error in Mysql

Comment: Look in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

Comment: try to see `tail -f /var/log/mysql/error.log` sir

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri Ohh realy.. I dont have mysql folder in /var/log .. Are you know solution without reinstall mysql

Comment: @Jos I dont have mysql directory in /var/log , /var/run .. can i fix it whitout reinstall .

Comment: stop mysql service first, and follow the command `cd /var/log && mkdir mysql && chown -R mysql.adm mysql && chmod 770 mysql` and then start again your service sir

Comment: also to make `mysqld` folder, try `cd /var/run && mkdir mysqld && chown -R mysql.mysql mysqld && chmod 755 mysqld` and start again your service.

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri It worked, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- **I found out how I got the errors of Apache and MySql. When i use the
  program for cleaning the cash, logs and etc in this case i have
  erased my directories Apache2 and MySql in /var/log/**

  **Here is the solution**

For apache2